# wso2 dss json format not working

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

Can we get JSON in Wso2 DSS directly when we select Output type as JSON in Create Query? I want to know without using curl, can we get? If yes, do we need to configure something extra along with selecting the Output type as JSON. This is because I am able to get data in Xml format from table but JSON throws error.

Comment: Have got some solution: The URL endpoint from DSS can be configured in ESB and JSON can be obtained in ESB.

Answer (score 1):

The request should be an HTTP/HTTPS request with the Accept header as 'application/json'. The following property should be enabled in the axis2.xml ($CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml). This is enabled by default.

```
<parameter name="httpContentNegotiation">true</parameter>
```